# Force Get-Date to use '/' as date separator

Tags: powershell

How can I get Get-Date to produce '/' as the date separator? There is a requirement to produce a en-US centric date format. It appears that PowerShell will always use the regional settings regardless of the format specified. It is set to '-' on my system, but I need to produce a date using '/'.

```
PS C:\src> Get-Date -Format MM/dd/yyyy
06-26-2017
PS C:\src> Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy"
06-26-2017
PS C:\src> Get-Date -Format 'MM/dd/yyyy'
06-26-2017
PS C:\src> Get-Date -Format "MM`/dd`/yyyy"
06-26-2017
```

The date separator is set to '-' on my machine. I do not find a Set-UICulture command.

```
PS C:\src> (Get-UICulture).DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator
-
```

Comment: What is the output of `Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy"` on your machine?

Comment: Modern versions of PowerShell make people incredibly lazy and sloppy.  Quotes are your friend when it comes to strings.

Comment: Using quotes does not change the result. Perhaps I am not lazy or sloppy.

Comment: perhaps...  but perhaps not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the format string, `/` represents the current UICulture date separator. To force it to be explicitly the `/` character, you must escape it using the `\` character:

```
Get-Date -Format "MM\/dd\/yyyy"
```

Comment: I thought the escape character in PowerShell was the GRAVE ACCENT (aka. backtick). This does work. Thanks.

Comment: Some commands use regular expressions for their patterns; those require the backslash (which is standard for regular expressions). The backtick is used where the pattern is PowerShell-specific.

Comment: If this solves your problem, you can indicate it by ACCEPTing the answer (checkmark below the up/down votes). That marks the issue as solved (and incidentally throws me a few points of rep).

Comment: I have been trying to mark it as the answer. SO forces you to wait 10 minutes before marking it as the answer.

Comment: This isn't a regular expression - the backslash is part of the custom format string. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#escape

Comment: Ah. Wasn't aware of the timeout. :)